# jq - How to iterate through nested keys with different names?

Tags: json, jq

I have data in the following format. Keys are unique across elements.

```
{
  "backend1": {
    "product1": {
      "subservice1": {
        "env1": {
          "KMS": "0.21",
          "DynamoDB": "235.91",
          "ElastiCache": "108.85",
          "Elastic Load Balancing": "324.29"
        },
        "env2": {
          "KMS": "0.21",
          "Elastic Load Balancing": "3.78"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "backend2": {
    "product2": {
      "subservice2": {
        "env1": {
          "KMS": "0.21",
          "ElastiCache": "108.85",
          "Elastic Load Balancing": "41.18"
        },
        "env2": {
          "KMS": "0.21",
          "Elastic Load Balancing": "3.78"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to iterate through the keys and transform JSON into Prometheus metric format.

```
aws_cost{env="env1",aws_service="KMS",product="product1",backend="backend1",subservice="subservice1"} 0.21
aws_cost{env="env1",aws_service="DynamoDB",product="product1",backend="backend1",subservice="subservice1"} 235.91
aws_cost{env="env1",aws_service="ElastiCache",product="product1",backend="backend1",subservice="subservice1"} 108.85
.....
```

I found that you can get keys at different indexes by using `.[] | .[] | .[] | .[]` but I do not know how to use a nested for loop to generate the data above. I'm open to other solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up with two ways to do it, one a little bit esoteric, the other a little bit brute-force. I'm providing both so that you can choose your favorite (and try to understand both).

Estoteric:

```
. as $data |
paths(scalars) | . as $path |
"aws_cost{env=\"\($path[3])\",aws_service=\"\($path[4])\",product=\"\($path[1])\",backend=\"\($path[0])\",subservice=\"\($path[2])\"} \($data | getpath($path))"
```

`paths(scalars)` produces paths to all of the leaf nodes (not objects or arrays) in the input. Each path is an array like `["backend1","product1","subservice1","env1","KMS"]`. You can see where we go with this — use the path itself to format the tag list, and use `getpath` to fetch the actual value. Some `as` shuffling is used so that `getpath` has the right `.` to operate on.

Brute force:

```
to_entries[] | .key as $backend | .value | 
to_entries[] | .key as $product | .value |
to_entries[] | .key as $subservice | .value |
to_entries[] | .key as $env | .value |
to_entries[] | .key as $service | 
"aws_cost{env=\"\($env)\",aws_service\"\($service)\",product=\"\($product)\",backend=\"\($backend)\",subservice=\"\($subservice)\"} \(.value)"
```

`to_entries` turns an object into an array of `key`/`value` pairs. For example, `{"a":1,"b":2}` becomes `[{"key":"a","value:1},{"key":"b","value":2}]`. We can use this to iterate over the keys at each level, capture the key using `as` for later use, and then put the value in `.` for further iteration. Then when we get to the bottom level, it's just string formatting.

Either one should be run with `jq -r` so that the output strings don't get re-encoded as JSON.

Comment: (The first one could use destructuring on the path, similar to how Jeff Mercado's answer does, but I'm going to leave it as is).

Answer (score 3):

Since the keys of the objects determine different values, you could do this rather nicely if you streamed the values in. Then you just need to parse out the parts of the paths and build up the results.

Stream, parse, then output.

```
$ jq --stream -r '
select(length == 2) as [[$backend, $product, $subservice, $env, $aws_service], $value]
  | {$env, $aws_service, $product, $backend, $subservice}
  | "aws_cost{\([to_entries[] | "\(.key)=\(.value|tojson)"] | join(","))} \($value)"
' input.json
```

```
aws_cost{env="env1",aws_service="KMS",product="product1",backend="backend1",subservice="subservice1"} 0.21
aws_cost{env="env1",aws_service="DynamoDB",product="product1",backend="backend1",subservice="subservice1"} 235.91
aws_cost{env="env1",aws_service="ElastiCache",product="product1",backend="backend1",subservice="subservice1"} 108.85
aws_cost{env="env1",aws_service="Elastic Load Balancing",product="product1",backend="backend1",subservice="subservice1"} 324.29
aws_cost{env="env2",aws_service="KMS",product="product1",backend="backend1",subservice="subservice1"} 0.21
aws_cost{env="env2",aws_service="Elastic Load Balancing",product="product1",backend="backend1",subservice="subservice1"} 3.78
aws_cost{env="env1",aws_service="KMS",product="product2",backend="backend2",subservice="subservice2"} 0.21
aws_cost{env="env1",aws_service="ElastiCache",product="product2",backend="backend2",subservice="subservice2"} 108.85
aws_cost{env="env1",aws_service="Elastic Load Balancing",product="product2",backend="backend2",subservice="subservice2"} 41.18
aws_cost{env="env2",aws_service="KMS",product="product2",backend="backend2",subservice="subservice2"} 0.21
aws_cost{env="env2",aws_service="Elastic Load Balancing",product="product2",backend="backend2",subservice="subservice2"} 3.78
```

Comment: thanks a lot. both the answers work perfectly and I had to chose the other one because of the explanations.

Comment: I suppose I could do that, but I had already explained what was relevant to the question, using the stream. I could probably go way more in depth into how every expression and construct used here works but it's not pertinent to the question. Anyway, it's your choice on what adequately answers your question. If a lengthy explanation is what you were after, that is something I could not provide at this time.

Comment: yeah, sorry. I don't think I'm fit to decide which answer is a better one and I can only choose one here.